# Flutter doctor failed

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

I installed Flutter on ubuntu 20.04 with "sudo snap install flutter --classic". after installation I run the flutter doctor. Unfortunately my internet was disconnected and I re-run "flutter doctor" command but i received below error:

> parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6 parse error:
> Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6 jq: error: syntax error,
> unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> [.releases[] | select(.hash==)][0].archive
> jq: 1 compile error Downloading / curl: (3)  malformed tar:
> latest_stable.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar:
> Error is not recoverable: exiting now Flutter initialization failed
> Could not find working copy of Flutter

I tested some solutions. for example, I removed flutter and reinstalled it. But I have the error yet.

[image]

Comment: activate vpn. then run the command.